# Why can't my phone write to external USB drive?

Tags: samsung, file-system, file-permissions, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I bought a new 3TB USB3.0 external harddisk for storing and transferring large files (mainly hd movies from my camera) between my Android phone (Galaxy S7 edge) and my PC (Win10).

Using windows, I...

- formatted the disk as exFAT
- transferred (moved) some folders with files to the drive
- created some new folders and transferred some files into those

Now when I plug this drive into my phone, it:

- can read and copy the moved directories and files
- can see the newly created directories
- can not see any files into the newly created directories
- can not create a directory anywhere on the USB drive
- can not edit or rename any files on the drive

My Phone

- is running Android 7.0
- is not rooted
- is using the default "My files" app

What do I need to do to give my phone full access to all files on the drive?

Comment: Try formatting the drive with your phone.

Comment: @esQmo_ thanks, I did that, but then it only created a partition of about 700GB and couldn't find a way to create a 3TB (full size) one

Comment: This phone doesn't support greater storage than 700MB? Does formatting as FAT32 in Windows helped ?

Comment: @esQmo_ The phone does support greater storage. I did not try FAT32 because the disk is way bigger than FAT32 supports.